# On isogonal mapping

Tags: complex-analysis

The definition of an "isogonal mapping" in $R^2$ is as follows.

Let $D$ be a domain in $R^2$.
An isogonal mapping $f:D\to R^2$ is a transformation that preserves the magnitudes of local angles, but not their orientation.

Question: A continuous isogonal mapping $f:D\to R^2$ is necessarily holomorphic or anti-holomorphic on $D$?

I believe the answer should be known "yes" but I donot find the proof in a suitable literature. I wish to know how to prove it.

EDIT. $f$ maps $C^1$ curves to $C^1$ curves, then "$f$ preserves the magnitudes of local angles" is well-defined as well as the angles. We donnot assume that $f$  is  differentiable in advance.

Comment: You should clarify what it means to "preserve the magnitudes of local angles" when $f$ is not necessarily differentiable. For differentiable maps this question [has been answered](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/150448/proof-that-angle-preserving-map-is-conformal).