# Why Riemannian metrics defining the same angles are conformal

Tags: linear-algebra, riemannian-geometry

Suppose $g_1$ and $g_2$ are two metrics defining the same angles, which means $g_1(X,Y)/(g_1(X,X)g_1(Y,Y))^{0.5}=g_2(X,Y)/(g_2(X,X)g_2(Y,Y))^{0.5}$ for all pairs of vector $X,Y$.I want to prove that $g_1=cg_2$ for a constant $c$. I have tried to use the polarization identity，but it doesn't work.

Comment: I think, you meant that $c$ is a function on your manifold rather than constant. Then, it is just a fact from linear algebra: if $A$ is an invertible linear transformation of $R^n$ which preserves angles, then $A$ has the form $cU$, where $c$ is a scalar and $U\in O(n)$. Do you need help with proving the linear algebra statement?

Comment: Similar questions have been asked (and answered!) a number of times: [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/150448/2002),  [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/177005/2002) and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/413443/2002), to name a few.

Comment: Vote to close as a duplicate?