# Prove that the $\lambda^2$ function of conformal mappings definition must be smooth

Tags: differential-geometry, conformal-geometry

Regarding [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/150448/proof-that-angle-preserving-map-is-conformal) question (if a map is angle-preserving then it's conformal), I'd like to show that, if $<d\phi_p(v_1),d\phi_p(v_2)>=\lambda^2(p)<v_1,v_2>_p$
then $\lambda^2$ is differentiable. I suspect we don't even need to pass through the definition of the function, but maybe we do.

I could only think of evaluating (1) in the same $v_1,v_2$ to see what happens. I can't really think of how to differentiate *with respect to $p$*. Should I try it by definition?

Any hints are appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your main equality holds for all $p, v_1, v_2$, apply the equality to unit-length $v$s with $v_1 = v_2$. Then you have
$$
\lambda^2(p) =\frac{<d\phi_p(v_1),d\phi_p(v_1)>}{<v_1,v_1>_p}\\
=\frac{<d\phi_p(v_1),d\phi_p(v_1)>}{1}\\
=<d\phi_p(v_1),d\phi_p(v_1)>
$$
and as long as $\phi$ is sufficiently smoothly differentiable, and so is the metric, you're done.

**Post-comment additions**
OP is apparently thinking of functions on some arbitrary manifold, $M$, so a little more detail is needed. What we're given is that for every $p \in M$ and every $v_1, v_2 \in T_p M$, 
$$
<d\phi_p(v_1),d\phi_p(v_2)>_{\phi(p)}=\lambda^2(p)<v_1,v_2>_p.
$$
where $\phi$ is a differentiable map from $M$ to some manifold $K$, and the inner product on the left is at $\phi(p) \in K$, while the one on the right is at $p \in M$ (i.e., on the tangent space $T_p M$).

The key thing to observe is that $\lambda$ is assumed to be independent of $v_1, v_2$.

OP wants to know whether $\lambda^2$ is differentiable as a function of $p$. The most general answer is "no, at least not obviously, for $d\phi$ may not be differentiable."

But if we're willing to assume that $\phi$ is twice differentiable, then this is a purely local question: we need only show that for any point $p_0 \in M$, $\lambda^2$ is differentiable in a neighborhood of $p_0$.

Pick a local coordinate system $x : U \to \mathbb R^n$ in a neighborhood of $p_0$; then the vector field $v(p) = \frac{\partial}{\partial x_1} (p)$ is nonzero at $p_0$ and throughout $U$. Let $v_1(p) =  v_2 (p) = v(p) / \| v(p) \|$ for $p \in U$. Then $v_1$ and $v_2$ are both vector fields on $U$, and unit length at every point, and their inner product, at every point, is 1. The assumed identity then tells us that 
$$
<d\phi_p(v_1),d\phi_p(v_2)>_{\phi(p)}=\lambda^2(p)<v_1,v_2>_p
= \lambda^2(p).
$$
If the inner product on $K$ is differentiable as a function of position, and if $d\phi$ is as well, then the chain rule allows us to compute the derivative of $\lambda^2$, hence $\lambda^2$ is differentiable.

Without the assumptions of a continuously varying metric, the theorem simply is not true. For instance, if we take the identity map on $\mathbb R^2$, where the domain has the usual metric, but on the codomain, the 
metric at $(a, b)$ is the usual metric for $a \le 0$, but twice the usual metric for $a > 0$, then the function $\lambda^2 (a, b)$ is $1$ for $a \le 0$ and $2$ for $a > 0$, which is evidently not even continuous.

If instead we pick the metric as the standard metric for $a \le 0$, but 
$(1+a)$ times the standard metric for $a > 0$, then the function $\lambda^2(a, b)$ is $1 $ for $a < 0$ and $1 + a$ for $a > 0$, which is continuous but not differentiable.

Hence the assumption of differentiability of the metric wrt position in the codomain is essential.

A similar example can be crafted to show that the assumption of differentiability of $d\phi$ is essential, I believe. I leave it to OP to give this a shot, following the model I've given.

*** Further additions ***

Let 
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases}
x-x^2 & x \le 0 \\
x + x^2 & x > 0
\end{cases}
$$
and
$$
\phi(x, y) = (f(x), y).
$$
Then 
$$
D\phi(x, y) = \begin{bmatrix} u(x) & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix},
$$
where
$$
u(x) = \begin{cases}
1-2x & x \le 0 \\
1x + 2x & x > 0
\end{cases}
$$
so $\phi$ is clearly continuously differentiable, but not twice differentiable.

For $p = (-a, 0)$ and $v_1 = v_2 = [1, 0]^t$, we have
$$
\newcommand{\ep}{\epsilon}
d\phi_p (v_i) = \begin{bmatrix} 1-2a \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} 
$$
so 
$$
\lambda^2(-a, 0) = (1-2a)^2
$$
Similarly, 
$$
\lambda^2(a, 0) = (1 + 2a)^2
$$
The derivative of the first, with respect to $a$, is $2(1-2a)*(-2)$; for the second, it's $2(1+2a)2$. The first, evaluated at $0$, is $-4$; the second is $+4$. Hence the derivative of $\lambda^2(t, 0)$, as $t$ passes from negative to positive through $0$, is undefined.

Comment: Right; I got there too, but I don't know if I really need $\phi$ to be "so" smooth. To start, I only need it $d\phi(v_0)$ to be differentiable respect to $p$ for any given $v_0$ of unit-length. I wonder if I need even less...
You answered my question, though. If in these days nobody gives an answer with less assumptions, then I'll mark yours as the correct one. Thank you very much!

Comment: No, wait. The vector $v_1$ depends on $p$. If $p$ changes, then $v_1$ may not be in the tangent plane of the surface!

Comment: In some local coordinate neighborhood around a point $p_0$, pick a vector field $v(p)$ that's smooth as a function of $p$ and nonzero at $p_0$. Let $U$ be an open set in that neighborhood with $v(p) \ne 0$ for $v \in U$ (possible by continuity).  Let $v_1(p) = v(p) / \| v(p) \|$. Then mu argument shows that $\lambda^2$ is smooth at $p_0$. Since you can do this for every $p_0$, the claim is proved. Apologies for not spelling this all out in the original answer.

Comment: See post-comment additions.

Comment: I picked $f(x,y)= (x^2,y^2)$ in the first quadrant, and $(x^2/2,y^2/2)$ otherwise (I tried to copy the integral of the module function, which is only once differentiable). It's also similar to the idea of your answer. Using the vector field in the tangent space (i.e. the plane) $(0,t)$ I got that $\lambda^2$ can't be differentiable at the origin.

Comment: (My $f$ mapped $\mathbb{R^2}$ to itself)

Comment: My counterexample for a non differentiable $d\phi$ didn't work and I've been trying with others and can't find any. Could you help me please?

Comment: Done. But at some point, you're gonna owe me a beer (or tuition!).

Comment: Jajaj, thanks! If you ever come to Argentina, you get a free beer!

...I think you should write $\phi(x,y) = (f(x),f(y))$ for it to be conformal, however. Do you want me to edit your answer?

(Example: if you pick $v=(v_1,v_2), w=(w_1,w_2)$ with all coordinates positive, $(p=(x_1,x_2))$, then $<d\phi_p(v),d\phi_p(w)>=(1+2x)^2 v_1 w_2 + v_2 w_2$, which is not proportional to $<v,w>$)

Comment: Hmm, no, now that I think about it, $(f(x),f(y))$ is not conformal also, as you stretch differently each coordinate, depending on which point you are at.

That's my problem, actually. Asking $\lambda^2$ to be conformal is making it really hard for me to find one that's only once differentiable.

Comment: Oooh...good point. I'll work a little more and rewrite...possibly not today. Keep that beer cold. :)